# java gwt celltable with checkbox

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox, celltable

I have a Cell Table of which the last column is a checkbox. I would like to add a Check-All-Box as a footer that when clicked selects every checkbox for every row. Somehow it won't work here is what I got so far:

```
Column<Object, Boolean> select = new Column<Object, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()) { 
        @Override 
        public Boolean getValue(Object object) { 
            return msm.isSelected(object); 
        } 
    }; 

    select.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Object, Boolean>() { 
        public void update(int index, Object object, Boolean value) {
            msm.setSelected(object, value); 
        } 
    }); 

    final Header selectAllHeader = new Header(new CheckboxCell()) { 
        @Override 
        public Boolean getValue(){ 
            return msm.getSelectedSet().size() == getRowCount(); 
        } 
    }; 

    selectAllHeader.setUpdater(new ValueUpdater<Boolean>() { 
        @Override 
        public void update(Boolean value) { 
            for (Object o : getVisibleItems) { 
                msm.setSelected(o, value); 
            }
        }
    }); 
        //works
    addColumn(select, selectAllHeader);
        //does not work
    //addColumn(select, HEADER, selectAllHeader);
```

Comment: I never use celltable. I just make my own one, easy and flexible. The one in GWT is so hard for human to use.

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution proposed here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7014

It works nicely. You can use it in your footer.

Comment: I tried it out (updated the code above) but only when I add the select all box in the header it works not when I add it as a footer why is that??

Comment: So have fixed this issue? if yes - please share your solution